# how to get the permission of the youtube analytics api for a channel

Tags: youtube, google-apis-explorer, youtube-analytics-api

my fellow created a project at google console, and he can always use the youtube analytics api to query a specific channel through oauth. Then he appointed me as an owner of the project, but when i used the same parameter to query the analytics api, it said i had not permission, as follow:

```
403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "errors": [
   {
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I think it's because i have no relative permission for these channel. but i have no idea how to get the permission of the youtube analytics api for a specific channel.
And i am confused that how is the project which is created in the google console associated to a youtube channel? Is't by the account who creates them?

Comment: Can you add some more detail about how you got this response? What type of auth did you use? etc.

Comment: Hi John. i use the following url of the apis explorer. Do i have to be assigned as a manager or owner of the targeted channel?                    
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=day&endDate=2018-10-30&ids=channel%3D%3DUCH9XrccQ1qdKpZYfq8BrquQ&metrics=views&startDate=2018-10-01&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: After i was assigned as a owner of the targeted channel, the problem was resolved.